# stange lines in videojs

Tags: html5-video, video.js

Started to use videojs.
When the download rate is slow and the video get stuk (while buffering) I get a very strange "jumping lines" effect.
Any ideas ?
Please take a look at the following short video :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=665XbXyz8Y8&feature=youtu.be
thx
Sagi

Answer (score 0):

That's the loading spinner, but you must have some CSS that's altering its appearance. Look for styles you have targeting `.vjs-loading-spinner`.